# resizing imageview internally without showing the result

Tags: android, imageview

i need to maximize an imageview and minimize another one by pressing a button , i do that perfectly but i dont want to show the result to the user ,, i dont want the user to see the new size (i want to do it internaly ) ,,, can anyone help me please ? this is my button code :

```
public void MaxMin (View v){
    int max = (int) (100 + (100 * 0.3));
    int min = (int) (100 - (100*0.3));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(max, max);
        iv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(min, min);
        iv3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `iv3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);`line

Comment: You created the new LayoutParams, if you don't want update your UI component with it, just don't set it to the view.